# Can varying the lower boundary of $ \int_0^x f(t) dt $ produce all antiderivatives of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am reading the [Wikipedia of antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative), where I find that

> Every continuous function $f$ has an antiderivative, and one antiderivative $F$ is given by the definite integral of $f$ with variable upper boundary:
> $$F(x)=\int _{0}^{x}f(t) \mathrm {d} t.$$
> Varying the lower boundary produces other antiderivatives (but **not necessarily all possible** antiderivatives). This is another formulation of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

My question: Is there a counterexample to show the claim "**not necessarily all possible** "? That is finding an counterexample to negate the following claim.

Suppose that $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $F'(x)=f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$F(x)=\int_b^xf(t)dt, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens for instance with $f(x) = \sin(x)$. Indeed, let $F(x) = \int_b^x \sin(t) ~dt$. Then for all $x$, we can compute $|F(x)| = |-\cos(x) - (-\cos(b))| \leq 2$. So any antiderivative reached in this way must be uniformly bounded between $-2$ and $2$. But there is an antiderivative not satisfying these bounds, for instance $-\cos(x) + 100000000$.

The antiderivatives for a function $\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ can differ by any real number, so I looked for a function where $\int_b^0 f(t) ~dt$ could *not* attain all real values.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. The only antiderivative you get with $\int_b^x f(x)\,dx$ is $0$ (irrespective of $b$), but any constant is also an antiderivative.